# Cargar archivo local con load() - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="checkbox" id="1" autocomplete="off"> 
    <br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Acá se muestra
            </td>
            <td id ="contenido">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- jQuery completo con ajax -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#1').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                // Se debe cargar una página hosteada en un servidor no en un archivo y se puede especificar una clase o id.
                $("#contenido").load("https://montesariel.com/es/contactos .heading")
            }
            if (!this.checked) {
                // Elimina el contenido si se desmarca la selección.
                $("#contenido").html("");
            }
        });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

El tema es que en la línea $("#contenido").load("https://montesariel.com/es/contactos .heading"), deseo reemplazar la url por un archivo local, pagina1.html, pero cuando lo reemplazo, no hace nada.

En el cmd usé el comando:

`chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Con la intención de que el navegador me permitiera utilizar la función load en archivos locales, pero sigue sin dejarme mostrar el contenido del archivo html.
Pueden darme alguna solución?
Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo controlar esta pregunta similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)

Comment: Gracias! Pude hacerlo creando el server